# DROP/ALTER Columns with Relationships

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, relationship, alter

I am very new to SQL and databases in general.  I have been following tutorials online to create tables with columns using SQL in MS Access 2010, then join them together using `JOIN` commands.  However, now that I have done that, I am attempting to `ALTER` the data type of some columns, and `DROP` commands to drop columns I feel are now unnecessary.  Unfortunately, I keep getting an error message saying, "Cannot delete/alter 'Column_Name'.  It is part of one or more relationships."  I know I can delete the relationships using the Relationships window in Access 2010, but will this delete my `JOIN`s, or would I simply have to run them again to reestablish the relationships?  Or, are relationships and `JOIN`s completely different?  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If you have a relationship between two tables, and you build a query with those tables in it, the join is automatically applied to your query. So, a relationship is a "thing" (which can be deleted), while a join is an instruction in a query.  You probably want to edit your relationships, to remove any columns you are dropping. Relationships aren't neccessary, but they make life easier.  Hopefully that helps some.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew.  Perhaps I can replace the relationships later without doing too much damage to the database?

Comment: If you are developing, consider using the interface, if you are creating an application, question why a user would need this power.

Comment: Hi, @Fionnuala.  I would love to use the interface, but I am taking a course in SQL and am trying to learn as much about its coding process as I can.  I ended up removing the relationships via the Relationships window, and emptying all of the fields of all records, altering and dropping the necessary columns, then repopulating the tables. Thank you for your feedback!